# Binary search on a list based on a property of the list type

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

I have a list of `T`, and the list is pre-sorted based off of some int index `ID`. I'd like to see if there's an element with an ID in it, so binary search is the quickest way.

Problem is I don't want to compare based on `T`, I want to compare based on the `ID` property.

Because the list is huge and it is at a slightly performance sensitive part of the application, applying some major transformation to the entire list would be out of the question (like `select`ing for `obj.ID`). It would be better to do the `O(lg n)` search and transform the items as the binary search continues doing it's job.

I tried getting a lambda to work by doing something like

```
// T = the List<T> type
// I = the type for transforming T -> I (as in I would be `int` in this example)
internal class BinarySearchHelper<T, I> : IComparer<I>
{
    private readonly Func<T, I> _transformer;
    private readonly Func<I, I, int> _comparer;

    public BinarySearchHelper(Func<T, I> transformFunc, Func<I, I, int> comparerFunc)
    {
        _transformer = transformFunc;
        _comparer = comparerFunc;
    }

    public int Compare(I x, I y) => _comparer(_transformer(x), _transformer(y));
}
```

but then I found out the hard way that `List<T>.BinarySearch()` operates off of the list type `T`, and not the type of the property that I want, so that is out because I want to search by ID (which is an `int` and not `T`).

I cannot find any standalone functions that do generic binary search, does one exist in the standard library (or even some common library I can add via nuget) that I can use? Or do I have to roll my own? Not that I mind rolling my own because the algorithm is trivial, but I like it when I don't write something that probably has been done elsewhere and is already unit tested. I don't know if I'm just missing one somewhere in some util class in the .NET ecosystem (.NET Core though, not Framework) or if I either have to look elsewhere or roll my own.

Comment: Use the [BinarySearch overload that lets you provide a comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) to compare the items by whatever property you like. Implementing IComparer is going to be less trouble than writing your own binary search.

Comment: Note that you'll want that to be a `IComparer<T>` so it compares `T` by `I`.  `_transformer` takes a `T` but you pass it a `I` in the `Compare` method.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How do I use that when the type for the first parameter is of type `T` when I am trying to search by `int`? I do not have an object of type `T` to compare against, am I to pass `null` to the parameter `T item` and let a custom comparator do its job? Unless I missed something in the MSDN.

Comment: @Water Just create a `T` with the value of `I` you want to search for.

Comment: @juharr Instantiating type T would likely be more work than rolling my own binary search due to the complexity of the object being searched for.

Comment: @Water If you really want to write the search, go for it. In a thousand years this will all be forgotten.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The whole post is specifically to _avoid_ writing binary search. Yes, I could spend a bunch of time writing it and doing a battery of tests (the annoying part) or do some interface hackery, but both of these solutions require a fair amount of code relative to what would be doable in a single line solution. As I'm sure you know, less code I have to write and other developers have to read = better. However what I want may not exist, and the correct answer for me would be "no, do X" where X is one of the two above solutions. I want to know if it's a yes or no first before doing X.

Comment: @Water Then that must be an incredibly complex class if you cannot just new one up and set a single property.

Comment: @juharr Whether it is or not is irrelevant with respect to the question.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a `Dictionary<int, T>` or even a `HashSet<int>` with just the ids so you can do a quick search for the id.

Comment: @Water It’s not irrelevant, if you’re insisting that it makes a given sensible solution impossible. But the Dictionary is certainly also an option.

Answer (score 2):

You need very little for a custom comparer that solves your requirements:

```
public class MyComparer : Comparer<MyClass>
{
    public override int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
}
```

If you want a generic one you can write up a class like this:

```
public class LambdaComparer<TSource, TKey> : IComparer<TSource> 
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private readonly Func<TSource, TKey> _keySelector;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
        }

        _keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    public override int Compare(TSource x, TSource y)
    {
        var xKey = _keySelector(x);
        var yKey = _keySelector(y);

        if (xKey == null) 
        {
            return yKey == null ? 0 : -1;
        }

        return _keySelector(x).CompareTo(_keySelector(y));
    }
}
```

And then wrap it up in an extension method for convenience:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<TSource, TKey>(
        this List<TSource> list,
        TSource item, 
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) where TKey : IComparable<TKey> => 
        list.BinarySearch(item, new LambdaComparer<TSource, TKey>(keySelector));

}
```

Finally a test:

```
var list = new[]
{
    "AVeryLongString",
    null,
    "NotLong",
    "A",
    "ZZZ"
};

var orderedByDefault = list.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
var orderedByLength = list.OrderBy(s => s?.Length).ToList();

var indexOfZZZByDefault = orderedByDefault.BinarySearch("ZZZ");
var indexOfZZZByLength = orderedByLength.BinarySearch(
    "ZZZ", 
    s => s?.Length ?? 0);

Assert.Equal(4, indexOfZZZByDefault);
Assert.Equal(2, indexOfZZZByLength);
```